# Search for unique numbers and copy their specific data to another sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have a workbook which has three sheets.

On Second Sheet named "Grade Wise" I have raw data.

On 3rd Sheet named "Sheet1" I want a button which will copy data from 2nd sheet to 3rd sheet.

On 2nd sheet, in column A and B data is repeated. These farmers have provided different grades with different weights.

I want to copy unique Farmer numbers and names (of column A and Column B) data for each farmer to 3rd sheet (As shown in attached picture).

In 2nd sheet, Column C has different grades, whose starting letters are X, C, M, B and their third letters includes A, F, C also.

CHALLENGE 1: I want to copy sum of all X to X (on 3rd sheet column D), sum of all C to C (on 3rd sheet Column E), sum of all M to M (on 3rd sheet Column F) and sum of all B to B (on 3rd sheet Column G) for each unique number--As Shown In Attached Picture.

(VBA CODE IS WRITTEN FOR THIS CHALLENGE AND IS WORKING BUT I WANT TO ADD BELOW OPERATIONS)

CHALLENGE 2: It should also look for third letter (A, F, C) and copy their Sum of all A to A (on 3rd sheet column N), Sum of all F to F (on 3rd sheet column O), Sum of all C to C (on 3rd sheet column P) as shown in attached pictures.

CHALLENGE 1 CODE IS:

```
Sub test2()
Dim c As Object ' Dictionary
Dim Ws As Worksheet
Dim toWs As Worksheet
Dim vDB, vNum(), vR()
Dim k As Long, i As Long
Dim x As Long, y As Long
Dim s As String

Set Ws = Sheets(2)
Set toWs = Sheets(3)

Set c = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

vDB = Ws.Range("a1").CurrentRegion

For i = 2 To UBound(vDB, 1)
    If Not c.Exists(vDB(i, 1)) Then 'Farmer NO.
        k = k + 1
        c.Add vDB(i, 1), k 'Farmer NO.
        ReDim Preserve vNum(1 To 3, 1 To k)
        vNum(1, k) = k
        vNum(2, k) = vDB(i, 1)
        vNum(3, k) = vDB(i, 2)
    End If
Next i
ReDim vR(1 To k, 1 To 10)
For i = 2 To UBound(vDB, 1)
    s = Left(vDB(i, 3), 1)
    y = c.Item(vDB(i, 1)) 'Farmer no
    x = getIndex(s)
    vR(y, x) = vR(y, x) + vDB(i, 4) 'Bales
    vR(y, 5) = vR(y, 5) + vDB(i, 4) 'Sum of Bales
    vR(y, x + 5) = vR(y, x + 5) + vDB(i, 5) 'New Weight
    vR(y, 10) = vR(y, 10) + vDB(i, 5) 'Sum of Weight
Next i

With toWs
    .UsedRange.Offset(2).Clear
    .Range("a3").Resize(k, 3) = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(vNum)
    .Range("d3").Resize(k, 10) = vR
    .UsedRange.Borders.LineStyle = xlContinuous
End With
End Sub


Function getIndex(v As String)
    Dim i As Integer
    Select Case v
    Case "X"
        i = 1
    Case "C"
        i = 2
    Case "M"
        i = 3
    Case "B"
        i = 4
    End Select
    getIndex = i
End Function
```

Sample data picture
[image]

Comment: What code did you try  by yourself?

Comment: I want a VBA code in excel

Comment: Dear i am new to VBA in excel, and i havent tried any code. I have copied the data to 3rd sheet manually. I want to automate this process by clicking one button. PLease help me

Comment: @ Dy.Lee i need your help please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple formula is enough once you populate the first Two columns Farmer No. (Selecting Unique Values from Data using Advanced Filter) and Farmer Name using Vlookup. Then all you need is one formula like `=SUMIFS($C$2:$C$18,$A$2:$A$18,$E2,$B$2:$B$18,F$1&"*")` and then you can copy it down.

See Image.

[image]

If you are worried to Automate this for new entries for fresh customers you can simply maintain a master sheet in the same workbook containing FarmerNo. and Names. Before making entry in data you just need to check if the farmer is in the master. This you can do with simple conditional formatting for duplicate Names. If you do so, you can even do away with the name column in the data or the farmer number col in Sheet3

Comment: I really appreciate your answer, i will try it.Can we do this through VBA please. I need to have just one button and by clicking it does the required job as you suggested

Comment: You can do it with VBA but.. I would suggest to use VBA if its not possible otherwise with simple formulas and simple excel tools. The advantage is simplicity. You can edit this any time you want. But someone who is not good at VBA will find it difficult again to edit the code...:) .. I hope you find solution soon.

Comment: Ok I got it .. You want full automation with a button.. And how are you going to populate the data sheet?.. You will have do it manually? Then I guess, clicking a button and Copying one line of formula in Sheet 3 would take almost same time?

Comment: hmm..you are right...i am trying but it,s not working...i m applying advanced filter  with unique values, but still it,s copying duplicate values too. can you please share your email, i will send the sheet to you. regards